# I'm trying to get Item Count from custom Adapter for a chat application but it always returns zero how to resolve this?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, custom-adapter

I'm making a chat application with RecyclerView and List class to store messages from Firebase Database and want to scroll at the bottom of the recylcerView when Chat Activity is opened but error is.....Adapter always returns zero while calling adapter.getItemcount() method . All messages are being displayed with no problem.

> Custom Adapter java file

```
public class ChatCustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{
                    private FirebaseUser mUser;
                    private String currentUser;
                    private List<ChatModel> msgList;

                    //Constructor
                    public ChatCustomAdapter(List<ChatModel> msgList) {
                        this.msgList = msgList;
                        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                        mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        currentUser = mUser.getUid();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public int getItemCount() {
                        return msgList.size(); 
                    }



                    @Override
                    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                        View v;
                        if(viewType==0){
                            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_single__user_item_layout,parent,false);
                            return new SelfViewHolder(v);
                        }else if(viewType==1){
                            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_single_other_user_item_layout,parent,false);
                            return new OtherViewHolder(v);
                        }else{
                            return null;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
                        int layout = holder.getItemViewType();
                        ChatModel model = msgList.get(position);
                        String msg = model.getMsg();
                        if(layout==0){
                            SelfViewHolder sHolder = (SelfViewHolder)holder;
                            sHolder.setSelfMsgItems(msg);
                        }else if(layout==1){
                            OtherViewHolder oHolder = (OtherViewHolder)holder;
                            oHolder.setOtherMsgItems(msg);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                        super.getItemViewType(position);
                        int layout;
                        ChatModel model = msgList.get(position);
                        String from = model.getFrom();
                        if(from.equals(currentUser)){
                            layout=0;
                        }else{
                            layout=1;
                        }
                        return layout;
                    }


                    class SelfViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
                        TextView msgtxt,timetxt;
                        SelfViewHolder(View itemView) {
                            super(itemView);
                            msgtxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_sinhle_user_item_textview);
                            timetxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_sinhle_user_item_timeview);
                        }

                        void setSelfMsgItems(String data){
                            msgtxt.setText(data);
                        }
                    }

                    class OtherViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
                        TextView msgtxt,timetxt;
                        public OtherViewHolder(View itemView) {
                            super(itemView);
                            msgtxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_other_user_item_textview);
                            timetxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_other_user_item_timeview);

                        }
                        public void setOtherMsgItems(String data){
                            msgtxt.setText(data);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

> Chat Activity java file

```
protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //region RETREIVING MESSAGES FROM SERVER
        msgQ = mDatabase.child("messages").child(current_user).child(otherusername).orderByChild("time");
        msgQ.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                ChatModel model = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatModel.class);
                mLsit.add(msgposition++, model);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        //endregion
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
  }
```

Comment: So where are you calling `adapter.getItemcount()` ?

Comment: `mLsit.add(msgposition++, model);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. What is `mLsit`? And what did you change for the adapter that you notify it for?

Comment: In the end of chat activity file...sorry i copied old code

Comment: mLsit is List to store the messages..
If any unnecessary line of code is there or any mistake please tell me ..thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think `getItemCount()` returns zero because you call this method outside of `ChildEventListener`. So you retrieve itemcount when there are no elements in `mLsit` yet. 
The fastest and a little bit dirty solution here is to put `scrollToPosition` in `onChildAdded` method. Also, I would modify code this way

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //region RETREIVING MESSAGES FROM SERVER
    msgQ = mDatabase.child("messages").child(current_user).child(otherusername).orderByChild("time");
    msgQ.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            ChatModel model = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatModel.class);
            mLsit.add(msgposition, model);
            mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(msgposition)
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(msgposition);
            msgposition++;
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
        });
        //endregion
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort..but i solved it.. problem was in the apadter's contructor..
Instead of "if..else if..else" ...i used only "if...else"